# Comparing sums of values inside array to determine which is the largest

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am working on a coding challenge and believe I am close to a solution, but am currently stuck and would appreciate some insight. I am trying to build a function that can take a set of numbers (credit card numbers including dashes), compare the sum of each number, and return the highest credit card number. The solution must utilize Javascript. The function is currently returning "undefined". Thanks in advance for any help!

```
function highestCredit(creditArray){
  var highSum = 0;
  var highIndex = 0;
  var sum= 0;
  //loop through each value in the array
  for (i = 0; i < creditArray.length; i++) {
    //loop that disregards dashes and adds up the sum of a single credit card number
    for (a = 0; a < creditArray[i.length]; a++) {
      if(isNaN(creditArray[i].charAt(a)) === false){
          sum += parseInt(creditArray[i].charAt(a));
      }
    }
    //compare current sum to highest sum, update the index if there is a new high number
    if (sum >= highSum) {
      highSum = sum;
      sum = 0;
      highIndex = i;
    }
  }
  return creditArray[i];
}

console.log(highestCredit(['4916‐2600‐1804‐0530', '4779‐252888‐3972', '4252‐278893‐7978' ,'4556‐ 4242‐9283‐2260']));
```

Comment: Hi - Welcome to stackoverflow.com.  Iuf you wish to get an answer you need to ask a specific question.  Is there something that is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had some errors, see working example

```js
  function highestCredit(creditArray) {
    var highSum = 0;
    var highIndex = 0;
    var sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < creditArray.length; i++) {
        for (a = 0; a < creditArray[i].length; a++) { // error with length
            if (isNaN(creditArray[i].charAt(a)) === false) {
                sum += parseInt(creditArray[i].charAt(a), 10);
            }
        }
        if (sum >= highSum) {
            highSum = sum;
            sum = 0;
            highIndex = i;
        }
    }
    return creditArray[highIndex]; // should return 'highIndex', not 'i'
}

document.write(highestCredit(['4916‐2600‐1804‐0530', '4779‐252888‐3972', '4252‐278893‐7978' ,'4556‐ 4242‐9283‐2260']));
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, don't you want to return `creditArray[highIndex]` instead of `creditArray[i]` ?

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues.

1. The `for (a = 0; a < creditArray[i.length]; a++) {` should be `for (a = 0; a < creditArray[i].length; a++) {`. The `.length` should be ouside the `[]`
2. At the end you need to return `creditArray[highIndex]`

Answer (score 0):

```
var creditCards = ["00-00-1-00", "00-00-2-00", "00-00-3-00", "00-00-4-00"];


function cardIdToObject(cardId) {
//remove the dashes
    var cardIDAsString = cardId.replace(/\D/g, '');
  //tansform the number as an array of character
  var cardIDAsArray = cardIDAsString.split('');
  // sum all the characters individually ..
  var cardIDAsInteger = cardIDAsArray.reduce(function(p,c){return p + parseInt(c) },0);
  //create an object containing the original id and the calculated sum for later comparison
  var cardAsObject={};
  //store the original id
  cardAsObject.id=cardId;
  //store the calculated sum of individual characters of the card number
  cardAsObject.sum=cardIDAsInteger;
  // returns object
  return cardAsObject;
}

function biggestCard(p, c, i) {
  return p.sum > c.sum ? p : c;
};

console.log("The biggest card id is :" + creditCards.map(cardIdToObject).reduce(biggestCard).id);
```

Comment: thanks ludovic, im a beginner so this is a bit over my head, but I'm going to spend some more time with this version to figure out how this works.

Comment: This is wrong as it treats the card number as an integer. The OP wants to sum the digits of the card and compare based on this sum