# Comparing sums of array of numbers javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sum

I am trying to sum numbers in an array, specifically credit card numbers and then compare the sums. I am using a function containing multiple for loops to break down the numbers into workable form, then summing them. I have gotten to the point that I sum the workable numbers, but am having difficulty getting a working sum.
Here is what I have done so far.
P.S. I do not want to use map or reduce for this as I am only trying to use what I currently know and understand to do this. Thanks.

```
var cardNumbers= ['4916-2600-1804-0530', '4779-252888-3972', '4252-278893-7978', '4556-4242-9283-2260'] ;

function creditSum(cardNumbers){
  var split=[];
  var join=[];
  var integer=[];
  var sum=0;
  var string=[];

 //regular expression splitting each number at non-alphanumeric characters
  for (var i=0; i<cardNumbers.length; i++){
    split[i] =cardNumbers[i].split(/\W+/g);    
  }

//joins split strings
 for (var j=0; j<split.length; j++){
      join[j]=split[j].join('');            
    }

    //turns each string into number
    for (var k=0; k<join.length; k++){
        integer[k]= +join[k];           

    //sums each digit of each number
    for (var m=0; m<integer[k].length; m++){
        sum[k][m]+= integer[k][m];
    }
    }
    return sum; 
}
console.log(creditSum(cardNumbers));
```

Comment: I bet there are several hundred similar questions on this site for this exact same excercise

Comment: You initialize `sum` to `0` but then your code treats it like a multi-dimensional array.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36533801/finding-max-sum-in-array-of-credit-card-numbers, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36094100/comparing-sums-of-values-inside-array-to-determine-which-is-the-largest, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38755062/how-to-find-sum-of-numbers-in-string-stored-in-array are some examples